# Create virtualedit block around selection

Tags: virtual, block, vim

I'm trying to create a script what permits me to select a few lines and create a virtualedit block around it; 1 column after the longest line.

This is my code

```
function! VirtualEdit()
  let EndLine = line("'>")

  set virtualedit = all

  let maxlength = max(map(range(line("'<"), line("'>")), "virtcol([v:val, '$'])"))-1
  call cursor(1,maxlength+1)  
  normal "^Q".EndLine."jc<space><ESC>"

  set virtualedit = ''
endfunction
```

What it must do is
1) Control the longest line in my selection (maxlength).
2) Put the cursor on the first line in the selection at the column of the longest line +1 column.
3) Than Activate Visual Block selection (on my windows pc the command is C-Q)
4) Extend the visual block till the last line in the selection (the command on my pc for moving down = "j").
5) Than use the "c" key to insert a "space" character and ESC to exit the insert mode in order to fill the virtual block column with spaces.

However I can't find out how to use a variable (Endline) in a normal command.
I noted also that keys as  and  don't work in my above example.
What did I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have many errors here:

1. `:set` does not let you have spaces around `=`
2. `:set` does not accept expressions, thus `set ve=''` is `let &ve="''"`, not `let &ve=''` which is `:set ve=`.
3. `:normal` command also does not accept expressions, it accepts strings that are just executed. Thus `:normal "^` is trying to use register `^`, fails (no such register) and stops processing the rest of the line. Use `:execute` to pass expressions to `:normal`.
4. `:normal` command does not accept `<Key>` syntax. Neither do viml expressions, they have `"\<Key>"` instead (note: only double quotes and with backslash). `^Q` syntax is not accepted by anybody and having raw control codes (displayed by vim as `^Q`) inside a text file is not the best idea.
5. Don’t use `:normal` without a bang. Most of time you don’t need it (you need to replace `^Q` with `\<C-v>` in this case though because it is a mapping).
6. Don’t hardcode `virtualedit` value. Instead of

   ```
   set ve=all
   <...>
   set ve=
   ```

   use

   ```
   let savedve=&ve
   set ve=all
   try
       <...>
   finally
       let &ve=savedve
   endtry
   ```
7. `{N}j` means “N lines down”, not “go to N’th line”. “Go to N’th line” is `{N}gg` or `{N}G`.
8. You have `let maxlen=<...>-1` and the on only line where `maxlen` is used you have `maxlen+1`. It is strange.

If you fix this you can proceed, but you don’t need adjusting virtualedit and using `:normal` at all:

```
function AddSpaces()
    let [lstart, lend]=[line("'<"), line("'>")]
    if lstart>lend
        let [lstart, lend]=[lend, lstart]
    endif
    let maxcol=max(map(range(lstart, lend), "virtcol([v:val, '$'])"))
    let newlines=map(range(lstart, lend), 'printf("%-'.maxcol.'s", getline(v:val))')
    call setline(lstart, newlines)
endfunction
```

Comment: Thank you ZyX! I'm learning every day but there is still so much things to learn. I will study your message a bit more. At the moment it gave this error; unknow function setlines.

Comment: @Remonn. Yes, it should be `setline`. Forgot to paste changes back from file I wrote my code to to test it, sorry.

Comment: Yes it works! Just one thing: what do I have to change to include also the selected empty lines in above function?

Comment: @Remonn What do you mean? It works with empty lines just like with other ones. // BTW, how do you call it from visual selection? There is a minor problem if you do just `vnoremap {lhs} :call AddSpaces()<CR>` that is often unmentioned, even by me: in this case it will be launched as many times as many lines there are in selection. Luck that subsequent runs do not change anything.

Comment: yes you're right.. Yesterday the empty lines remained empty but today (don't know what I've changed) the empty lines are included. Thanks ZyX. Btw..how many years are you using (g)vim? ;)

Comment: Zyx, you wrote about `:Normal`. In a visual block I want to use the `o` key to switch to the other side but it doesn't work when I use the `:normal \o` or `:normal "o"` or whatever doesn't work in my vimscript. I just can't find out how these normal command work.

Comment: @Remonn What is “in visual block”? `:normal! o` may work normally depending on what you meant. And finally read the help, I do not get where you got these `\o` or `"o"` syntaxes, but definitely not from help and not from me.

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with this question.:) You answer is great! I was trying to move my cursor from one side to the other side in a visual block ("o" key), tried hours to insert all kind of things in my vimscript (normal o, normal "o", normal \o, normal "\o" but nothing works) --http://jvi.sourceforge.net/javahelpset/jvi-vis_block.html

Comment: @Remonn I missed “to switch to the other side” part. I don’t know how you can do this using `:normal` (maybe `:normal! gvo`, but I am not sure) because I typically do this things using `<expr>` mappings, `normal! o` does not work because `:normal` executes in normal mode, visual is a separate one.