# How to normalize whitespace for block of text in vim?

Tags: vim

Suppose I have a file (newlines marked as ^n):

```
aaaa^n
                        bbbb^n
cccc^n
```

Is there a simple command to backfill whitespace to the rightmost portion of the block (probably using a visual selection); I often see questions about removing leading whitespace, but in this case I want leading whitespace normed to the longest non-whitespace character in the block, like below:

```
aaaa                        ^n
                        bbbb^n
cccc                        ^n
```

Comment: An interesting, somewhat related problem (and answer) is at [Vim get length of matched line](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13324093).

Comment: See also my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057562/create-virtualedit-block-around-selection

Comment: Get the [tabular plugin](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probaly the easiest way would be to do

```
set virtualedit=all
```

Go to the top left of the block you want to select. Use a Blockwise visual selection (`<C-V>`) and select the the lines you want. Then hit `$` to extend the visual block to the end of the line.

Then yank the selection with `y`

Then type `gvp` to past what you yanked lines back onto it self. (`gv` reselects the last visual block). When you are done this will extend all lines to be the length of the longest line + 1.

The reason this works. When you are using a virtual edit the visual selection is extends each line to the length the longest when putting it into the register.

This will add an extra space to the end which is easily fixable with with `:%s/ $//`

Comment: +1 excellent use `'virtualedit=all'`. I found that this works great except it adds an extra space at the end of each line. Easily fixed with `:%s/.$//`.

Comment: @PeterRincker yeah I was noticing that too and was looking for a setting to get rid of it.

Comment: I think this is because how `$` works. It always goes one place past the last character of the line. I wish there was a `g_` for visual block mode.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in a single `:substitute`, although it does get a little involved:

```
:'<,'>s/$/\=repeat(' ', max(map(getline(line("'<"),line("'>")),'strdisplaywidth(v:val)'))-strdisplaywidth(getline('.')))/
```

This command applies to the Visual selection. If you need more control over the range, consider wrapping the substitute in a function that accepts a [`range`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#function-range-example).

How does it work?

- `\=` in the replacement string lets you evaluate an expression: see [`:h sub-replace-expression`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#sub-replace-expression).
- The replacement is a number of padding space characters: `repeat(' ', ...)`.
- The exact number of space characters is determined as the difference between

  - the maximum line length in the selection, `max(map(getline(start,end), 'strdisplaywidth(v:val)'))`, and
  - the width of the current line, `strdisplaywidth(getline('.'))`.

Note that [`strdisplaywidth()`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#strdisplaywidth%28%29) is not available in older Vims, but it is necessary to handle both tabs and spaces in the line correctly. (Use `strlen()` as a cheap substitute.)

Comment: This isn't the best solution, in my opinion, but I _am_ a little bit awed by that command.

Comment: for one time job, this is a little too much. however, if this operation needs to be done very often, this could be written as a function or mapping to make this kind of operation very easy. just visual select, then press `ABC`  +1!

Comment: @Kent glts wrote a function and mapping but then removed it. Check the edit history if you want to see it.